# Can I convert/decode a JPEG file that is in binary with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, aws-lambda

I'm sending a JPEG file into an AWS Lambda function as binary in a POST request body, and I was wondering if Tensorflow has a way to convert this binary into an image that could be passed into:

```
tf.image.encode_jpeg()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a JPEG image to a tensor, you need to call `tf.image.decode_jpeg()`. The following code should work:

```
queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['image.jpg'])
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, jpg_data = reader.read(queue)
tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpg_data)
```

Comment: Where abouts would my binary data fit into that? Say, if the variable for it was called `binaryData`?

Comment: I've never tried decoding a binary variable. If you create a string tensor from the data, you should be able to call `tf.image.decode_jpeg(binaryData)`. Does this give you an error?

Comment: When I use `tf.image.decode_jpeg(binaryData)` (with nothing else before it) I get the error: `Invalid JPEG data, size 11594\n\t [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable...`

Comment: OK, if you display `type(binaryData)`, what's the result?

Comment: The type is unicode according to my CloudWatch logs. The log also displays the error `Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf` which I assume comes from this: `image_jpg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)`